# Nuxt 3 dynamic route decorate parent page

Tags: routes, dynamic, vuejs3, nuxt3

I currently have a Nuxt 3 app with a default layout (header and footer)
In between them the pages are shown.
Now I have a good working `/map` page showing a leaflet map inside my layout.

The next thing was showing and zooming in on individual hotels shown on the map.
I got this working via get parameter `/map?showHotel=2` but this wasn't very SEO friendly.
I wanted something like `/map/hotel/2` so I started working with dynamic routes.

```
/map
  /hotel
    [name].vue
  index.vue
```

My `[name].vue` file looks now like this:

```
<template>
  <p>{{ $route.params.name }}</p>
</template>
<script setup>

</script>
```

This prints out the hotel name inside my default layout, but not showing map page anymore.

So how can I show just my `/map` page like before and use the hotel id to trigger my `flyto()`function?

I can maybe move that `flyTo()` logic from `/map/index.vue` to `/map/hotel/[name].vue` and basically don't have to render html so template can be empty?

I had played around with `<slot />` etc, but could not get the map view to show up.
I can imagine someone building a webshop with links like `webshop.com/product/3` has the same challenge. You only need to decorate data onto product page right?

Answer (score 0):

there are many methods for example `rewrite` your route or interven with `extendRoutes`, `redirect`...

Although `redirect` is the best way for SEO but I prefer this method:

[name].vue

```js
<script>
import index from ".."

export default index
</script>
```

Note: that since this method uses something rather brute force that it serves multiple purposes you have to multi-select to get `showHotel`
index.vue

```js
<script lang="ts" setup>
const showHotel = computed(() => {
  return props.name ?? route.params.showHotel
})
// or if you not enable props mode:
const showHotel = computed(() => {
  return route.params.name ?? route.params.showHotel
})
</script>
```